Formal view on one-sided limits for maps of real variable
I was studying mathematical analysis when a question came to my mind.
It is well known that, for maps of real variable, is it possible to define one-sided limits. Employing topology (or metric space theory), it is easy to interpret them as limits of functions defined in subspaces. But the left and right neighbourhoods of a point aren't just two of many possible ones, since the existence of a two-sided limit is equivalent to the coincidence of left limit and right limit (loosely speaking, and making it precise requires laying down the definitions one presupposes). I feel this last aspect not easy to link to a proper formal setting.
Is there some notion (in topology, or analysis, etc.) formalising the role that, in the previous context, one-sided limits have with respect to general limits? or, more likely, the role that right neighbourhoods and left neighbourhoods have with respect to general neighbourhoods?

You need a totally ordered space to make sense of right (larger than) and left (less than).

@Medo I am aware. What I was referring to is not much the ordinal interpretation, but rather the fact that the two sub-neighbourhoods are exhaustive of the original one: in this sense, the fact that they are obtain ordinally doesn't seem so relevant; they may be three or infinitely many, but it's the exhaustiveness of whom I'm searching for a formalisation.

I don't have a complete answer to your question, but the notion of a limit with respect to a filter seems relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filters_in_topology#Limits_of_functions_defined_as_limits_of_prefilters
